# Oracle DataReader get sorted even with an ORDER BY clause in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, datareader

I have a simple SELECT query :

```
SELECT id, name FROM myTable ORDER BY id
```

When I execute it in Oracle, I get it sorted letters first.

```
ID         NAME

A          ValueA                                       
B          ValueB                                       
C          ValueC                                       
1          Value1                                       
2          Value2                                       
3          Value3
```

When I execute it in my VB project, the datareader sort it according to my CultureInfo even with the ORDER BY

```
Dim dictio As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
strQuery = "SELECT id, name FROM myTable ORDER BY id"
rs = New OracleCommand(strQuery, myConnection).ExecuteReader()
Do While (rs.Read())
   dictio.Add(rs.Item(0), rs.Item(1))
Loop
```

I get my rows in the dictionary ordered like this:

```
ID         NAME

1          Value1                                       
2          Value2                                       
3          Value3
A          ValueA                                       
B          ValueB                                       
C          ValueC
```

I guess this issue come from .NET itself, sorting the rows when it put them into a list and using my CultureInfo.

Do you know how to get rid of it and tell it to use the raw data?

Comment: Er.. VB won't sort the data unless you tell it to, and nothing in your VB is sorting. Dictionary(Of T,T) is not a sorted collection. Are you sure that your query tool and your VB are using the same NLS_SORT ? Run `select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter='NLS_SORT';` in both the query tool and VB and tell us the results. SOunds to me like Oracle is giving you the data in one order for your query tool and another for your VB

Answer (score 0):

Regardless the actual technicalities of your query and why the data is coming out in different orders depending on the route you take to running the query, sorting data is generally the purview of the front end/visualization strategy rather than the database

Pull your data out of the DB in whatever order it comes, without an ORDER BY, and then sort it in your VB into whatever order you want to show it to the user:

```
Dim dictio As New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
                  ^^^^^^
                sort by key


strQuery = "SELECT id, name FROM myTable"
rs = New OracleCommand(strQuery, myConnection).ExecuteReader()
Do While (rs.Read())
   Dim id as String = rs.Item(0).ToString()
   id = Char.IsDigit(id(0)).ToString()(0) + id
   dictio.Add(, rs.Item(1))
Loop
```

Rather than make my own comparer here I chose the cheap and nasty route of modifying the key used for the sort; all the letters will return False from Char.IsDigit, and prepending the ID with the F will mean they sort before the T that is prepended to digits

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.

I don't really want to sort the datas in my application.
In fact, this application is a migrated one from ASP(VB6) to ASP.NET(VB.NET) and there is a lot of datareaders like this one. So I'm hopping to find a solution resolving all the cases in one shot.

I tried the query you gave me, and it helped a lot. Now, I'm quite sure my issue come from this.

Here are the results:

- In Oracle itself: **FRENCH**
- In VB with culture set to en-US: **BINARY**
- In VB with culture set to fr-FR: **FRENCH**

My dream goal is to keep my main culture to en-US  (mostly for dates in the application), and executing my query as if it was the fr-FR one.

Do you know if I can, in some way, execute a query with a specified culture ? I couldn't find a easy solution to do it...

Comment: This is not an answer.  Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60511778/edit) your question and add this information to it.  Then delete this answer.